# va_start unexpected behavior

Tags: c, std, microcontroller

I'm currently working on a STM32 MCU that communicates by Serial link (UART Communication) with a serial terminal installed on my computer (TeraTerm).

I've implemented a function on my STM32 whose behavior is the same as printf. To do so I used va_start MACRO, va_list, vprint and va_end.

Here are the different functions :

--> printf like (using UART function to send data)

```
/**
 *  \fn APP_errors_t SER_send_multiple(char* ui8_data_p, ...)
 *  \brief  function to send multiple data (like the printf function) via the serial link
 *  \param  ui8_data_p, string that will be sent via serial link
 *  \param  ... next data
 *  \return Any of the following values:
 *          SER_OK_E : if init is a success
 *          other : value if failure
*/
APP_errors_t SER_send_multiple(char* ui8_data_p, ...)
{
    APP_errors_t ret;
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, ui8_data_p);
    ret = vprint(ui8_data_p, argp);
    if(ret!= SER_OK_E)
    {
        SER_send("Error in SER_send_multiple function\r", strlen("Error in SER_send_multiple function\r"));
    }
    va_end(argp);
    return ret;
}
```

--> function vprint used to combine all splited

```
/**
  * \brief APP_errors_t vprint(const char *fmt, va_list argp)
  * \param fmt This is the C string that contains the text to be written to the str
  *  \return Any of the following values:
  *         SER_OK_E : if init is a success
  *         other : value if failure
*/
// todo, cas ou le message à envoyer est trop grand ?
static APP_errors_t vprint(const char *fmt, va_list argp)
{
    char string[SER_TX_MAX_SIZE];
    if(0 < vsprintf(string,fmt,argp)) // build string
    {
        return SER_send(string, strlen(string));
    }
    // dead code
    return SER_OK_E;
}
```

--> function called by the function above

```
/**
 *  \fn APP_errors_t SER_send(char* ui8_data_p, uint16_t ui16_size)
 *  \brief  function to send data via the serial link
 *  \param  ui8_data_p, string that will be sent via serial link
 *  \param  ui16_size, number of chars that we want to send
 *  \return Any of the following values:
 *          E_OK : if init is a success
 *          other : value if failure
*/
APP_errors_t SER_send(char* ui8_data_p, uint16_t ui16_size)
{
    if(HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)ui8_data_p, ui16_size, SER_SEND_TIMEOUT) != HAL_OK)
    {
        return SER_TRANSMIT_ERROR_E;
    }
    return SER_OK_E;
}
```

So what's the problem ?

In an other function i'm calling SER_send_multiple(char* ui8_data_p, ...) function :

```
SER_send_multiple("Pin does not exist  %s \r", args[OFF_PIN]);
```

args is a char * array :

[image: Wrong pin char *]

but on TeraTerm i'm receiving :

[image]

so the MCU is just sending the first char.

Here is all the code (the first line is just a test) :

```
SER_send_multiple("Pin does not exist :  %s \r", args[OFF_PIN]);
SPCMD_arguments_T const * pins = &all_pins_a[inc];
while(ui8_found != 1 && pins->name_cmd != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(args[OFF_PIN], pins->name_cmd ) == 0) {
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = pins->value_define;
        ui8_found = 1;
    }
    pins = &all_pins_a[++inc];
}
//uint8_t length = strlen(args[OFF_PIN]);
if(!ui8_found)
{
    SER_send_multiple("Pin does not exist :  %s \r", args[OFF_PIN]);
    return 1;
}
```

Finally if I uncomment uint8_t length = strlen(args[OFF_PIN]);
TeraTerm is receiving :

[image: succes_wrong_pin]

So what the hell is going on there ? This is a non sens, uncommenting this line shouldn't change the bahavior of my application ?

Any clue ?

Regards

AJT

Comment: Suggest `char string[SER_TX_MAX_SIZE]; ... vsprintf(string,fmt,argp)` --> `vsnprintf(string,sizeof string, fmt,argp)` to mitigate potential buffer overflow.

Comment: This symptom suggests that you have undefined behavior somewhere in the program.

Comment: "This is a non sens" is probably more accurate than you realize.  Very likely you have some undefined behavior going on here, which could be characterized as the source being in some way nonsensical, or else providing for the program to attempt a nonsensical action.

Comment: It's quite common that adding or removing a seemingly inoccuous statement like that changes the impact of a buffer overflow, because it changes the stack layout.

Comment: A useful test for the return value of `vsnprintf()` is `int count = vsnprintf(string,sizeof string, ...); if (count >= 0 && count < sizeof string)  Success(); else Failure();`.  AJT, try this code to prevent   UB and report if it helps.

Comment: What is `args`? Where does it point to? `Here is all the code` it definitely is not __all__ the code.

Comment: regarding: `return SER_send(string, strlen(string));`  the expression: `strlen(string)` is not a stable method.  What should be used is the value returned from `vsnprintf()`,  which should be used rather than `vsprintf()`

Comment: Ok i found the solution thanks to @KamilCuk. Args was an array of char * but all strings stored in args were local variables. So, sometimes theses char * were not modified by the program, sometimes they were. That's why adding a code line could change the behavior of my program ! Thank you all !